# Why use '/' instead of other characters for routing

Tags: url, web, routes

In terms of routing urls for the web, it's standard practice to use the character `/` to separate routing urls.

Ex:

```
www.example.com/i/like/programming
```

Is there a specific reason, such as search engine optimization, that this is the standard way to generate urls?

However, it's also easily possible, especially with frameworks such as *Symfony2* or *Zend*, to make routing patterns like so:

```
www.example.com/i<>like<>programming
```

I want to know specific reasons why special characters are not (or shouldn't be) used in place of the character `/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention is named Uniform resource locator. Wikipedia has a great article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)